# How to add a specific property to a container using extension in flutter

Tags: flutter, extension-methods

I am trying to experiement with flutter's `extension` function . So far i have made a good progress, But stuck in modifying a specific property of container keeping all of its previous properties intact .

Sample Worked in `TextStyle`

```
extension Theme on Text {
   Text red() {
    return Text(data!, style: style?.copyWith(color: Colors.red));
   }

   Text bigFont() {
    return Text(
      data!,
      style: style?.copyWith(fontSize: 22),
     );
  }
}
```

And use as `Text("Hello",style:TextStyle()).red().bigFont()`

Output:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I want to achieve the same using `Container` but it doesn't have `copyWith` property.i.e I want to make a roundedCorner and then add linear Gradient to it using two different extensions.

Presently my try:

```
extension sample on Container {
  Container roundedCorner([Color? color, int? x]) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(x?.toDouble() ?? 20)),
        child: this);
  }

  Container addGradient(Color colorStart, Color colorEnd) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [colorStart, colorEnd])),
      child: this,
    );
  }
}
```

Using it as

```
Container(child: Text("Hello"))
                .roundedCorner()
                .addGradient(Colors.green, Colors.lightGreen);
```

Output:

[image]

Expected Ouput:

[image]

Note: This is happening because of nesting of `Bordered container` within `Gradient container`. How to overcome this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension sample on Container {
  Container roundedCorner([Color? color, int? x]) {
    return Container(
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(x?.toDouble() ?? 20),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(),
          ),
          child: this,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container addGradient(Color colorStart, Color colorEnd) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [colorStart, colorEnd]),
      ),
      child: this,
    );
  }
}
```

Then add the gradient before clipping like so:

```
 Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
                child: const Text(
                  "hi",
                ),
              ).addGradient(Colors.red, Colors.orange).roundedCorner(),
```

Comment: Thank you ! , this work around works for this example. But i am trying to make it more flexible and more customizable . So i am looking forward for a more generic and a to point answer to my question